# AddAttachment from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, sendgrid

The SendGrid API docs specify you can add attachments from a Stream. [The example it gives uses a `FileStream` object](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp#how-to-add-an-attachment).

I have some blobs in Azure Storage which I'd like to email as attachments. To achieve this I'm trying to use a `MemoryStream`:

```
var getBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(fileUploadLink.Name);
if(getBlob != null)
{
  // Get file as a stream
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  getBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
  emailMessage.AddAttachment(memoryStream, fileUploadLink.Name);
}
emailTransport.Deliver(emailMessage);
```

It sends fine but when the email arrives, the attachment appears to be there but it's actually empty. Looking at the email source, there is no content for the attachment.

Is using a `MemoryStream` a known limitation when using the SendGrid C# API to send attachments? Or should I be approaching this in some other way?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You probably just need to reset the stream position back to 0 after you call `DownloadToStream`.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Having SendGrid in the title makes perfect sense. It's a question which is specific to SendGrid. Why have you removed it? It's not a tag, it's a fundamental part of the question. Someone who is a SendGrid expert might now see the title and dismiss it because it doesn't mention SendGrid. Neither your snarky comment or your edit to the title are helpful.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen *SendGrid*  is actually a tag you've added. Please ... simply follow my provided link to get some more insights on this topic!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I understand and am aware of the point about having tags in the title. I felt in this case having SendGrid in the title made sense. Others (you) may disagree and that's fine. However I don't think your condescending tone is helpful.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen I strongly believe you got me wrong - may it be the fact that English is not my mother tongue ... Sry if my tone was offending you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following which fixed the issue for me:

```
fileByteArray = new byte[getBlob.Properties.Length];
getBlob.DownloadToByteArray(fileByteArray, 0);
attachmentFileStream = new MemoryStream(fileByteArray);
emailMessage.AddAttachment(attachmentFileStream, fileUploadLink.Name);
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably just need to reset the stream position back to 0 after you call `DownloadToStream`:

```
var getBlob = blobContainer.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(fileUploadLink.Name);

if (getBlob != null)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    getBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin); // Reset stream back to beginning
    emailMessage.AddAttachment(memoryStream, fileUploadLink.Name);
}

emailTransport.Deliver(emailMessage);
```

You might want to check who cleans up the stream as well and if they don't you should dispose of it after you've called `Deliver()`.

Comment: Saved my day. Was struggling for this for past 20 hours. Thanks @Lloyd

Answer (score 1):

According to their API, they have implemented `void AddAttachment(Stream stream, String name)`.
You are probably using a `MemoryStream` which you have written to before. I suggest resetting the position inside the stream to the beginning, like:

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Read the code, you'll notice MemoryStream is a new object which hasn't been written to before. I will, however, try your (and Llyod's) suggestion.

Comment: @lee_mcmullen that is not fully true: `getBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);` which writes to the stream but might not reset the position afterwards ...

Answer (score 0):

The thread is a bit old, but I use a varient with NReco PDF converter:

```
    private async Task SendGridasyncBid(string from, string to, string  displayName, string subject, **byte[] PDFBody**, string TxtBody, string HtmlBody)
        {
            ...
            var myStream =  new System.IO.MemoryStream(**PDFBody**);
            myStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            myMessage.AddAttachment(myStream, "NewBid.pdf");

            ...
        }
```

convert the html to pdf and return it instead of writing it for download...

```
    private byte[] getHTML(newBidViewModel model)
    {
        string strHtml = ...;

        HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
        pdfConverter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--page-size Letter";

        var pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(strHtml);

        return **pdfBytes**;
    }
```

I am not sure how efficient this is, but it is working for me and I hope it helps someone else get their attachments figured out.