# Using MemoryStream Send .txt attachment with email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, sendgrid

I have been looking through many answers on this I just can't quite seem to understand how to do it though, even if its glaringly obvious.

I want to write values from a table in my database to a text file and attach the text file to an email without storing it locally. I am using Sendgrid API to manage sending the email and I was attempting to use MemoryStream to store the data.

Below is what I have attempted

```
private MemoryStream WriteToTextFile(IEnumerable<Location> locations)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine($"{location.Time},{location.Location},{ location.LocationAccuracy},{ location.IsAlertRaised}");
        }
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
    return memoryStream;
 }
```

Then my attempt to attach it to the email

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var message = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);    
message.AddAttachment(memoryStream, fileName);
var response = await _client.SendEmailAsync(message);
memoryStream.Dispose();
```

The error is straightforward "cannot convert from *'System.IO.MemoryStream'* to 'string'

The solution I was attempting was based on a question asked here.
[AddAttachment from MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122352/addattachment-from-memorystream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. The `using` block in the first sample will call `streamWriter.Dispose()` before returning the stream. The `Dispose()` operation will **close** your MemoryStream, leaving it unusable.
2. The example code from your link seems to be using a different, possibly older, version of the SendGrid API. Looking at [the current API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/a6fcf87fc848289e7bc9f6e45dd406bcc65c7c93/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs), the only overload from the `AddAttachment()` family that accepts a stream looks like this:

   ```
   public async Task AddAttachmentAsync(string filename, Stream contentStream, string type = null, string disposition = null, string content_id = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
   ```

All of the other options required a `base64content` string instead. You can also just read the code for the method in the API link above for a good example of how to convert that stream to base64.